# Next dynamic route & Link behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Say I have a page `pages/shop/[[...slug]].js`

I visit this page `pages/shop/beer` where beer is the slug.

The first way, if I type this URL into the address bar and hit enter, from the middleware I get `request.NextUrl.href === "http://localhost:3000/pages/shop/beer"`, no problem it works as expected.

The second way, I have a `<Link href="pages/shop/beer" as="pages/shop/beer">` from the home page, however, this time it prints out like this `"http://localhost:3000/pages/shop/beer?slug=beer"` Where is the `?slug=beer` from? I wasn't expecting that.

If the route prints `/[[...slug]].js?slug=beer` I can understand why, okay we don't know what slug is, so we attached it to the url query params. But since we already know it is `beer`, why does the route have to be `beer?slug=beer`? That looks unnecessary & inconstant, I can prove that with the First way, with slug it works anyway.

Is there a way to tell Next `<Link>` not to add that slug?

Comment: Can you use an object in the href?  You could try `{{
    pathname: '/pages/shop/beer',
    query: { },
  }}`

The only time I see a question mark like that is when the query object is set to something, so there might be some value getting read there that shouldn't be

Comment: @fordat did as you suggested. Unfortunately, it is still the same result.